# Unable to send array through Jquery.post

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, post

So,I have an array of input values:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="write your Question" id="question[]"  value="" />
```

and I'm sending this inputs through this code:

```
    $.post("function.php",{Question:$("#question").serialize()},function(data){
        $("#construct").append(data);
        alert('done');
    });
```

But when I try to use these values in my PHP,I have some errors.

PHP(function.php):

```
$Question=htmlentities($_POST['Question'],ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
//line 13
$Quiz->InsertQuestion($Q_id,$Question[0]);
//line 14
$Quiz->InsertQuestion($Q_id,$Question[1]);
```

the error says:

> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in E:\program file\program\xampp\htdocs\QMS\admin\function.php on line 13
>
> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in E:\progrram file\program\xampp\htdocs\QMS\admin\function.php on line 14

thanks in advance.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['Question']);` And btw `question[]` and `question` are **different** ids.

Comment: @u_mulder I used `var_dump` and I got:`string(0) "" `.btw I thought when I want to send an array so I should use `question[]`!

Comment: Can you post all of your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, `id="question[]"` and `id="question"`  are different ids.
If you want to send items as an array you should use `name` attribute with `[]`:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="write your Question" name="question[]"  value="" />
<input type="text" placeholder="write your Question" name="question[]"  value="" />
```

jquery:

```
// select all fields which names start with "question"
{Question:$("[name^='question']").serialize()}
```

or even `class`:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="write your Question" value="" class="question" />
<input type="text" placeholder="write your Question" value="" class="question" />
```

jquery:

```
{Question:$(".question").serialize()}
```

Comment: it seems when I use `.serialize()` I can't get the complete value

Answer (score 0):

Change the id of input from "question[]" to "question".

Comment: Why did he want to change that if he wants to pass an array of questions?

Comment: Because it is an id of a DOM content.

Comment: @Ahmadbaba46 I did it but still failed:-(